# Maven inherit dependencies from a project into another

Tags: java, maven, bamboo

Given a Maven project A producing a jar:

```
<groupId>myprojects</groupId>
<artifactId>A</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.needed.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>some.needed.artifact1</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>some.needed.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>some.needed.artifact2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and a project B depending on A and producing an enterprise archive:

```
<groupId>myprojects</groupId>
<artifactId>B</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<packaging>ear</packaging>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

how can I achieve to have the project B ear artifact to include not only the project B's jar artifact but also its dependent artifacts some.needed.artifact1 and some.needed.artifact2?

---

I edited and added this because it seems that the behaviour occurs only when running mvn from Bamboo:
The strange thing is that it is working when I'm running mvn locally from Eclipse but not when it's being ran by the Bamboo continuous integration server. On a local run I have the application.xml generated correctly with references to all the transitive dependencies the corresponding jar files copied to the lib folder. On Bamboo plan the generated application.xml does not include the references and the jar files are not in the lib folder.

Comment: It already should; dependencies are transitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First as a correction I think dependency should be on A, not on B , like this :

```
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>A</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

And about the original question of having the dependent jars , i think they should be available in your EAR file , as you have dependency on `A project` and which in turn depends on `some.needed.artifact1 and some.needed.artifact2`(transitive dependencies) as the scope you provided is **default so maven will take it as compile** and all the jars will be bundled in your ear file.

Thanks

Comment: Indeed, I had mistyped the artifactId. I have re-edited and corrected it in my text.

Comment: the strange thing is that it is working when I'm running mvn locally from Eclipse but not when it's ran by the Bamboo continuous integration server. On a local run I have the application.xml generated correctly with references to all the transitive dependencies and these are copied to the lib folder. On Bamboo plan the generated application.xml does not include the references and thease are not in the lib folder.
I'll continue to search.

Comment: Umm sorry Bamboo do not come under my umbrealla :( . You can tag your question under Bamboo so that other Bamboo experts can help you on that. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

In project B which produces the ear, you can include a dependency to  A like this

```
<modules>
  <module>project A</module>
</modules>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>some.needed.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In project A, define the parent project to be project B like the following

```
<parent>
        <groupId>myprojects</groupId>
        <artifactId>B</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <name>project B</name>
</parent>
<name>project A</name>
```

Comment: Only a project packaging 'pom' can define modules; project A cannot include such reference as it's packaging 'ear'.

Comment: I guess you did not read my answer correctly. There is nowhere in my answer that says project A packages the ear as you yourself you indicated project B packages the ear. I said above to define project B as the parent for project A in project A pom and include project A as a module in project B pom, that way you can package directly project A jar file when building project B

Comment: In my previous answer I meant project "B". No project other than reactor (pom packaging) can define modules.

Comment: which is exactly what I said, project B is your reactor and where you define module for project A right?